# format for time from php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I start with a standard html form 
and store that input in a mysql field type=time(6)
It stores fine. I am trying to create a php page for modifying the fields (in case an user keyed in the wrong info) The "modification page" performs this function to tweak the format so the html control works and shows the correct value:

```
value=<?php echo substr($row['timefield'], 0, -10); ?>
```

When I try to insert those fields back into mysql, I get

> "Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax;:

The original field value was: `02:02:00.000000` in MySQL;
the value that is being inserted has changed to: `02:02`
(without the substr function, the controls don't show the data).
How should I format the data for inserting back into mysql?

variable=
$timedispatched = $_POST['timedispatched'];

$sql="UPDATE tablename SET timedispatched=$timedispatched where id = $rowid";

I have also tried:
$timedispatched = $_POST['timedispatched']."000000";
and several other variants.

Comment: The error is in your query construction, can you please edit your post with the query you are using for the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried solution like this ?

```
$time = substr($row['timefield'], 0, -10);
$mysqltime = date("His",strtotime($time));
```